# How to integrate apache nutch with apache solr on linux?

Tags: solr, glassfish, nutch

I am using glassfish server and eclips IDE. I already downloaded apache solr and configured into glassfish. Now I stucked integration of nutch with solr.

As I new to these concepts, can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

[NutchTutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial) covers step by step instructions for configuring Nutch and Solr Integration